# How to install drivers on Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, drivers, wifi

How can I install a driver on any Linux?

I have XG-762 Sagem adapter on USB with the ZyDAS 1211B chipset, and I don't have drivers for it. What should I do?

PS: Despite it should be in my file system. It isn't...

Answer (score 4):

According to [this page](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/zd1211rw/devices), the driver's name is `zd1211rw`. Is that missing from your filesystem? Depending on your distribution, you can re-install the kernel and/or kernel modules. The driver isn't on 2.4.25 (the earliest Linux version I have lying around), but it definitely is on 2.6.32.

If you manage to find the driver and it's just not getting loaded, you should check to see that the particular vendor/device IDs are detected properly by the driver, though. To do this, say `lsusb` and find the *vendor:product* IDs for the Sagem device. You could then say `sudo modinfo 1211rw` and check the ‘modalias’ lines to see if your device is supported. If your device has a product ID of 1234 and a devide ID of 5678, you should look for `v1234p5678`. Feel free to use `grep` or `less`, the driver has a ton of supported devices listed.

Comment: It's missing. How should I reput it there? Just during installation I didn't maybe chose package with drivers, but I want to do it now.

Comment: I'd like to add just kernel module. I don't have any particular knowledge about drivers on linux.

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: Linux Arch 2.3.3.1 . I just installed it.

Comment: I just checked the Arch website, and the file listing for the [i686 linux package](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/testing/i686/linux/) clearly includes zb1211rw.ko.gz. It appears to be `lib/modules/3.2.4-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/zd1211rw/zd1211rw.ko.gz`. If your installation doesn't have it under a similar directory (with *your* kernel version in the name, of course), perhaps you should reinstall the `linux` package. It might also help to say `locate zb1211rw` to see if the driver module is stashed somewhere weird.

Comment: I give up. I'm going to reinstall system. I was asking u if u could tell me how to do it just like that by copying some files. Isn't it possible?!

Comment: Where would you copy files *from*, if the driver is missing from the filesystem, as you say? If you reinstall the kernel package, it will also reinstall all its drivers including the one you want. I can't provide you with a magical, catch-all command that will recover the driver without knowing something about your system. The fastest way forward is this: re-install the linux kernel package (`linux`) and see if the driver appears afterwards. Reinstalling the system every time you get into trouble is the wrong way forward. You *may* fix the problem, but you'll never *learn* from it.

Comment: Exactly, and if you happen to find the solution and post it here, it will help people in the future. Actually it's really hard to help you debug, you didn't give enough information and maybe you missed something. This is the best answer you can get with this question.

Answer (score 2):

It's like other OS, too. But Linux has many drivers included. Maybe you are missing some newer drivers and you need to download a newer kernel or install a new distribution?